# Place buttons next to MPart tabs

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I need to find a way to add buttons next to the MPart tabs located on a MPartStack. How can I do this in Eclipse E4?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean a tool bar for the current part you do this by clicking the 'ToolBar' check box on the Part page in the Application.e4xmi. Once you have done this a 'Toolbar' child will be added to the design where you can add tool items.

ToolBar check box in part page:
[image: Toolbar checkbox]

ToolBar in part design:
[image: Toolbar child]